# Mangler function for DES?

Tags: security, des

The Mangler function takes as input 32 bits, and expands it to 48 bits.  It does this breaking the 32 bits in 8 4 bit chunks and concatenating the left and right bits to each chunk.  My question is this.  Where do the first four bit chunk get the left bit from?  Would it take it from the last bit of the last chunk?  Or would it simply concatenate a 0.  This applies to the last 4 bit chunk as well, except they would need to get the right bit which does not exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Expansion Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material#Expansion_function_.28E.29) takes the last bit from the last "chunk" and prepends it to the first "chunk" and the last "chunk" gets its rightmost bit from the leftmost bit in the first "chunk".

```
   32-bits  =>      48-bits
--------------------------------
 1  2  3  4 => 32  1  2  3  4  5
 5  6  7  8 =>  4  5  6  7  8  9
 9 10 11 12 =>  8  9 10 11 12 13
13 14 15 16 => 12 13 14 15 16 17
17 18 19 20 => 16 17 18 19 20 21
21 22 23 24 => 20 21 22 23 24 25
25 26 27 28 => 24 25 26 27 28 29
29 30 31 32 => 28 29 30 31 32  1
```

This illustration shows it quite clearly:

[image]